# How do I make a 3-way comparison for a file-count?

Tags: powershell

I have a script that will count the files on a folder based on an interval. It will write the number of files in the folder and color-code it. My issue is that I need it to return 3 values: green, yellow, or red.

If the files are, say, less than 10, output the foregroundcolor as green.
If it's more than 10, but less than 20, output foreground color as yellow.
If it's more than 21, output as red.

How do I put a cap on the mid range values, so red can show by itself?

```
$Counter = Read-Host "Enter Update Interval"
$timeout = new-timespan -Minutes 1
$sw = [diagnostics.stopwatch]::StartNew()

Write-Host "Outbound Script"
$Counter
while ($sw.elapsed -lt $timeout){
  if ((Get-ChildItem \\server\folder).count -le 12) {
    Write-Host (Get-ChildItem \\server\folder).count "Items in Outbound" -ForegroundColor Green
  } else {
    Write-Host (Get-ChildItem \\server\folder).count "Items in Outbound" -ForegroundColor Yellow
  }
  start-sleep -seconds $Counter
}

Write-Host "Times-Out"
```

I tried making a variable for all the `Get-ChildItem`, but for some reason it will only count once if I do it that way.

Comment: Show the attempt you made with the variable? Is the question here just how you add another `if` test to the mix?

Answer (score 2):

```
$Counter = Read-Host "Enter Update Interval"
$timeout = new-timespan -Minutes 1
$sw = [diagnostics.stopwatch]::StartNew()

Write-Host "Outbound Script"
$Counter
While ($sw.elapsed -lt $timeout){
    $FileCount = (Get-ChildItem \\server\folder).count

    If ($FileCount -le 10) {
        Write-Host "$FileCount Items in Outbound" -ForegroundColor Green
    } ElseIf ($FileCount -ge 11 -and $FileCount -le 20) {
        Write-Host "$FileCount Items in Outbound" -ForegroundColor Yellow
    } Else {
        Write-Host "$FileCount Items in Outbound" -ForegroundColor Red
    }

    Start-Sleep -seconds $Counter
}

Write-Host "Times-Out"
```

Comment: Thanks Peter. In the future you can edit posts by clicking the edit link at the bottom to fix these minor errors.

Comment: That's no so easy for a single character... you have to change at least 6 ;-)

Comment: You don't need `$FileCount -ge 11 -or` in second `if`. First, it's simply wrong: you have to use `-and` (otherwise it always evaluates to `$true`), second, it's already covered by first `if`, no need to check it second time.

Comment: You're right about the `-or` switch. I fixed it. But I left the other part for clarity. You are right though it could be omitted.

Answer (score 2):

Depending on how crazy your conditions get using a [switch](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh847750.aspx) here would be beneficial. Also, hopefully not going overboard, we can use [splatting](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj672955.aspx) to make it so that if your message text ever changes you are only editing the one line.

```powershell
$filecount = (Get-ChildItem \\server\folder).count
$color = @{}

switch($filecount){
    {$_ -le 10 }{$color.ForegroundColor = "Green"}
    {11..20 -contains $_}{$color.ForegroundColor = "Yellow"}
    {$_ -gt 20}{$color.ForegroundColor = "Red"}
}

Write-Host "$FileCount Items in Outbound" @color
```

`11..20 -contains $_` covers the range requirement. If the `$filecount` is between 10 and 21 that condition becomes true. A more technical explanation: `11..20` creates an array of numbers using the range operator and we use `-contains` to see if one of the elements is `$filecount`. Be careful on the order of conditions you have here.

Comment: I love the use of splatting, but why would they need to be careful of condition order? The `$filecount` can only ever match one condition for what you have shown there, so order shouldn't matter right?

Comment: @TheMadTechnician yes for what I have shown in this case. But if the OP takes this and does something different then the use of `break`s might be needed. I was just trying to suggest that the conditions are not mutually exclusive (<- i think thats what I mean)

Comment: Fair enough, the conditions in a `switch` are definitely not mutually exclusive unless explicitly designed to be (such as in your example). BTW, I would suggest using `Continue` when possible in switches, since `Break` can have undesirable effects depending on where it's used. I remember reading some strange cases, like embedding a `switch` in a `ForEach-Object` and using `Break` stopped the `ForEach-Object` or something crazy like that.

Comment: @TheMadTechnician .... I always get break and continue mixed up in switch. Thanks for the reminder.

Answer (score 1):

Add an elseif statement.

```
IF ((Get-ChildItem \\server\folder).count -le 12) {...}
ELSEIF ((Get-ChildItem \\server\folder).count -lt 20) {...}
ELSE {...}
```

Comment: I would refrain from repeating the same cmdlet call. Its needlessly redundant and inefficient. Just store it in a variable.

Comment: Another thought: While it is unlikely, it is possible that the file count could change between condition checks.

Comment: Perfect thanks! the elseif did it as well as a -ge -and  command thanks everyone!